# Remote form in Rails not resetting

Tags: jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Don't know why this is happening, but after submitting a form via JS (using JQuery), it's not resetting.

_problem_form.erb

```
<%= form_for [@industry, @problem], "id" => "problem_form", :remote => true  do |f| %>
  //fields
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
<% if @problem.errors.any? %>
  $("#errors").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'layouts/error_messages', :locals => {:object => @problem })%>");
<% else %>
  $("#problem_form_area").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=> 'problems/problem_form') %>");
  $(".problem_area").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @problems) %>");
  $("#problem_form")[0].reset();
<% end %>
```

The POST request is sent and I can see everything update normally. The form just doesn't reset.

The really strange part is that normally after a a successful POST, all the assets are fetched. However, this time, the server just hangs at

> Completed 200 OK in 132ms (Views: 88.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

and the logs don't indicate any GETs to my CSS or JS files.

On a side note, if I click on the submit button again (after the first POST and without refreshing the page), I get this message:

> Started PUT "/industries/1/problems/71" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-06
>   18:49:51 -0500
>
> AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'update' could not be
>   found for ProblemsController):
>
> Rendered
>   /Users/hansy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/unknown_action.erb
>   within rescues/layout (0.6ms

So, not sure why my form is converting the method from POST to PUT.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is #problem_form_area? Don't you need to send @problem to <code>  $("#problem_form_area").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=> 'problems/problem_form') %>");</code> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first submit creates a new problem record (which is done by a POST request).

The same @problem is being sent back to the view. So now the form will update that record (which is done by a PUT request)

Comment: oh right of course that makes sense! how do I avoid this? The form is located on other model's (Industry) Show page (Problem is nested within Industry). How do I get `@problem` to go back to equaling `Problem.new(:industry => @industry)` instead of carrying over from the recent record?

Comment: I probably should just redirect to the page, but then my validations don't seem to work appropriately :(.

Comment: If you can explain why you need :remote => true, then I could suggest something. Also, it looks like :industry :has_many :problems and you are viewing the industry's page. So it will be better if you have a form_for :industry, with nested_attributes_for :problems, and your IndustryController#update should automatically create a new problem for that industry upon @industry.update_attributes (params[:industry]). Please look at the formtastic, client_side_validations, slim - wonderful gems!

Comment: Originally I wasn't using remote=>true, but my form has a few fields, and if one or more of them doesn't pass validation, the entire form is reset. I want to maintain the validated fields after page reset, but the problem is, the object is lost after the redirect to the Show page.